# How to initialize a time variable in R?

Tags: r, variables, time

I am trying to set a time variable in order to use it for comparison against times stored in a vector and am writing the following:

```
> openingTime <- as.POSIXct('08:00:00 AM', format='%H:%M:S %p', tzone = "EET")
> openingTime
[1] NA
```

Also

```
> dput(openingTime)
structure(NA_real_, class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")
```

What am I doing wrong there?

Comment: You are missing a `%` sign in front of `S`, and you should use `tz`instead of `tzone`. Try `openingTime <- as.POSIXct('08:00:00 AM', format='%H:%M:%S %p', tz = "EET")`

Comment: Incorrect syntax = `NA`.

Comment: Thanks, that did it!

Comment: @Rhertel In a similar fashion, if  I were to create an empty time variable which would be filled when executing a function, would the following suffice?

`emptyvariable <- as.POSIXct(0, format='%H:%M:%S %p', tz = "EET", origin = '01/01/1970')`

Comment: No, the command you posted returns `NA`. You need to provide information on a date in a format that corresponds to the type specified in `format=..`. What would be the purpose of creating an empty variable? In R, a variable is usually created by assigning a value to it. There are exceptions, such as empty lists or empty matrices, but I don't see the point in this case. If you really want to pass a variable of the class POSIXct to a function, you might start with a bogus date, knowing that it will be changed into a meaningful one after the function call.

Comment: @RHertel I'll probably set a bogus date, as you said it will be updated during the function call. (btw, I have no way to mark your 1st comment as answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35100973/how-to-initialize-a-time-variable#comment57923037_35100973) and pointed out by @[rhertel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4770166/rhertel), the proper syntax in order to get the variable working is:

`openingTime <- as.POSIXct('08:00:00 AM', format='%H:%M:%S %p', tz = "EET")`